# how to generate a modified version of identity matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a modified version of the identity matrix, call it **C**, such that **Cii** is zero until some index **i**, the rest is still 1.

I can use brute force to set **Cii** to 0, but I think that is not good.

Is there any efficient functions I can use, this is hard to search.

Example below:
the original identity matrix for 3 * 3 is

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

, I want to change this into:

```
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

so the **i** is 0 in this case, want to change Ckk, k goes from [0, i] to 0.

Comment: As far as I know, an identity matrix has 1's on the identity diagonal and zeroes everywhere else - it sounds like what you want is different, perhaps give an example? If you don't want anything different, starting with `zeroes` is fairly efficient, please show what you have and ask if people know how to approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.diag` makes a 2d array from a 1d diagonal:

```
In [97]: np.diag((np.arange(6)>2).astype(int))                                                 
Out[97]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

basically the same as PPanzer's, but generating the diagonal a different way.  Similar speed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility:

```
N = 5
k = 2

np.diag(np.bincount([k],None,N).cumsum())
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Update: fast solution:

```
out = np.zeros((N,N))  
out.reshape(-1)[(N+1)*k::N+1] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build an NxN identity matrix and assign zero to the top left KxK corner:

```
 N,K = 10,3
 im  = np.identity(N)
 im[:K,:K] = 0

 print(im)
```

output:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

40% faster than hpaulj's but not as fast at Paul Panzer's fast solution (which is 3x faster than this)

Comment: *"That is probably the fastest approach."*  --  most definitely not.